# tkinter + OpenCV WebCam Very Slow Video Stream

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am using tkinter and opencv for the first time and have successfully built a GUI for my project, however, I cannot figure out why my video stream is updating so extremely slow. I am grabbing frames very quickly but it seems that the update on the screen gets exponentially slower. I am seeing somewhere around 30 seconds of lag when I first launch the program but it eventually slows to a halt. I am connecting to three cameras but only displaying one at a time. The cameras all display and the selection buttons work. My only issue is the display refresh rate.

This is running in Python3.7 on a raspberry pi4. I can connect to the camera via web browser and it appears to have no lag.

I have been searching for answers but cannot seem to find anything that helps. Can anyone offer some help with this?

Here's my program (I have removed unrelated code):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
from tkinter import *
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


#GUI
class robotGUI:

    def __init__(self):

        self.selectedCam = "front"
        self.window = Tk()

        #Setup the window to fit the Raspberry Pi Touch Display = 800x400 and align top left
        self.window.geometry("800x480+0+0")
        self.window.overrideredirect(True)
        self.window.fullScreenState = False

        #Create Frame for Video Window
        self.videoFrame = Frame(self.window, relief=SUNKEN, bd=2)
        self.videoFrame.place(x=0, y=0, height=457, width=650)

        #Create the Video Window
        self.video = Label(self.videoFrame, bd=0, relief=FLAT, width=644, height=451)
        self.video.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.vid = VideoCapture()
        self.camUpdateFreq = 250
        self.updateCams()

        #Create the Button Frame
        self.buttonFrame = Frame(self.window, relief=FLAT)
        self.buttonFrame.place(x=651, y=0, height=457, width=149)

        #Create Buttons
        #Select Front Camera Button
        self.frontCamButton = Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Front Camera", command=lambda: self.selectCam("front"))
        self.frontCamButton.place(x=24, y=50, height=30, width=100)

        #Select Boom Camera Button
        self.boomCamButton = Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Boom Camera", command=lambda: self.selectCam("boom"))
        self.boomCamButton.place(x=24, y=130, height=30, width=100)

        #Select Rear Camera Button
        self.rearCamButton = Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Rear Camera", command=lambda: self.selectCam("rear"))
        self.rearCamButton.place(x=24, y=210, height=30, width=100)

        #Close Button
        self.exitButton = Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Close", command=self.window.destroy)
        self.exitButton.place(x=24, y=400, height=30, width=100)

        #Start the main loop for the gui
        self.window.mainloop()

    def selectCam(self, cam):

        if (cam.lower() == "front"):
            self.selectedCam = "front"
            self.statusBarLeft['text'] = "Front Camera Selected"
        elif (cam.lower() == "boom"):
            self.selectedCam = "boom"
            self.statusBarLeft['text'] = "Boom Camera Selected"
        elif (cam.lower() == "rear"):
            self.selectedCam = "rear"
            self.statusBarLeft['text'] = "Rear Camera Selected"

    def updateCams(self):

        #Get a frame from the selected camera
        ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame(self.selectedCam)

        if ret:
            imageCV2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = Image.fromarray(imageCV2)
            imgPhoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
            self.video.imgPhoto = imgPhoto
            self.video.configure(image=imgPhoto)

        self.window.after(self.camUpdateFreq, self.updateCams)
        


#Video Camera Class
class VideoCapture:

    def __init__(self):

        #Define Locals
        FrontCameraAddress = "rtsp://admin:password@192.168.5.20:8554/12"
        BoomCameraAddress = "rtsp://admin:password@192.168.5.21:8554/12"
        RearCameraAddress = "rtsp://admin:password@192.168.5.22:8554/12"

        #Open Front Video Camera Source
        self.vidFront = cv2.VideoCapture(FrontCameraAddress)
        self.vidBoom = cv2.VideoCapture(BoomCameraAddress)
        self.vidRear = cv2.VideoCapture(RearCameraAddress)

        #Verify that the Camera Streams Opened
        if not self.vidFront.isOpened():
            raise ValueError("Unable to open video source to Front Camera")

        if not self.vidBoom.isOpened():
            raise ValueError("Unable to open video source to Boom Camera")

        if not self.vidRear.isOpened():
            raise ValueError("Unable to open video source to Rear Camera")

    #Get One Frame from the Selected Camera
    def get_frame(self, camera="front"):

        #Attempt to Get Front Camera Frame
        if (camera.lower() == "front"):

            #If Stream Still Open Return a Frame
            if self.vidFront.isOpened():
                ret, frame = self.vidFront.read()
                if ret:
                    #Return a boolean success flag and the current frame converted to BGR
                    return (ret, frame)                
                else:
                    return (ret, None)
            else:
                return (ret, None)

        #Attempt to Get Boom Camera Frame
        elif (camera.lower() == "boom"):

            #If Stream Still Open Return a Frame
            if self.vidBoom.isOpened():
                ret, frame = self.vidBoom.read()
                if ret:
                    #Return a boolean success flag and the current frame converted to BGR
                    return (ret, frame)                
                else:
                    return (ret, None)
            else:
                return (ret, None)

        #Attempt to Get Rear Camera Frame
        elif (camera.lower() == "rear"):

            #If Stream Still Open Return a Frame
            if self.vidRear.isOpened():
                ret, frame = self.vidRear.read()
                if ret:
                    #Return a boolean success flag and the current frame converted to BGR
                    return (ret, frame)                
                else:
                    return (ret, None)
            else:
                return (ret, None)

        else:
            return (False, None)

    #Release the video sources when the object is destroyed
    def __del__(self):
        if self.vidFront.isOpened():
            self.vidFront.release()
        if self.vidBoom.isOpened():
            self.vidBoom.release()
        if self.vidRear.isOpened():
            self.vidRear.release()
            

#Main Routine  - Only run if called from main program instance
if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:

        #Create GUI Object
        app = robotGUI()            

    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: " + str(e))

    finally:
        print("Cleaning Up")
```

**NOTE:** In this copy of the program, I am updating every 250ms but I have tried smaller numbers down to around 3 but the frames still seem to be behind. Is there a better way to do this?

**NOTE2:** After working with this more today, I realize that openCV is definitely buffering frames for each camera starting when the cv2.VideoCapture() function is called for each camera. The read() function does seem to be pulling the next frame from the buffer which explains why it is taking so long to update and why the image I see on the screen never catches up to reality. I changed my test code to only connect to one camera at a time and use the cv2.release() function any time I am not actively viewing a camera. This improved things quite a bit. I also set the update function to run every 1ms and I am using the grab() function to grab a frame every cycle but I am only processing and displaying every 10th cycle which has also improved some. I still have some lag that I would love to remove if anyone has any suggestions.

My RTSP stream shows with zero noticeable lag when viewed in a web browser. Does anyone know how I can get the same effect in tkinter? I am not married to openCV.

Comment: You read frame from the camera every 250 ms, not fast enough.  Even though you increase the frequency, don't expect too much.

Comment: @acw1668 I have taken this down as far as 1 ms but not alot of change. Actually down around 1 will start bogging down the gui altogether. I don't need a fast frame rate, I just need the frames to be current. At present, it seems like the frames are being buffered and I am only peeling off one frame from that buffer at a time, instead of grabbing one live frame directly from the camera.

Comment: I don't have the issue using your code (of course I have only one camera, not three).  I can get the current frame (maybe a bit delay).

Comment: I created a stripped down version of this code with only one camera and I am seeing a decent delay of maybe 2 seconds. I have not studied opencv so I dont fully understand what it's doing under the hood. I would think that the read function would grab one frame from the incoming stream but that is not what it appears is happening.